# How can I access an IBOutlet in ViewController from another class?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class that is a `GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate`. Now I'm getting some data thru UDP (in a background thread) and need to display that data with an IBOutlet in my ViewController. But ViewController is just a class. Where is its object instance defined? What is its name? What do I do to access it, or one of its properties, methods? I've seen this `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController` method but this doesn't guarantee the exact ViewController I want to access, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact structure of your app, but you could try something like this:

```
let rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController

if let customViewController = rootViewController as? CustomViewController {

    customViewController.label.text = theData
}
else{ 
    let customViewController = storyoboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CustomViewControllerID")
    // (This assumes CustomViewController is defined in the same 
    // storyboard as the view controller running this code. Otherwise, 
    // you need to get a reference to the storyboard first).

    rootViewController.presentViewController(customViewController, animated:true)

    customViewController.label.text = theData
}
```

---

**EDIT:** If the object that receives your asynchronous server data is dettached from your navigation (good call, by the way), you can have it:

1. Store the data somewhere it will persist even if said object is deallocated
   (or make said object a singleton, if applicable).
2. Post a system notification (using `NSNotificationCenter`) once the data is available, and have your main `ViewController` "listen to it" (`-addObserver:selector:name:object`). When the notification is posted and the notification handler is called, your view controller can retrieve the data from its (persistent) location (file, or property of the singleton mentioned above if you chose that route).
3. Finally, for the case when the data is already available by the time your `ViewController` is instantiated, check for data availability and retrieve it if present in e.g. your main view controller's  `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Even though this method works, it's a slow (and still looks dirty) solution. That's why I tried to avoid to go thru UIApplication. Or is it not as slow as I think it is? I'm getting like 100-150 udp packets per second to process and update display with some charts, graphs and text objects.

Comment: I repeat: I don't know the overall structure of your app: The code that gets called when you receive your data, where does it reside? Inside a view controller? Inside a model object, or a singleton?

Comment: I mean, where are you on your app's navigation when the data arrives from the server? You need to design that. With asynchronous operations, you don't know what the current view controller will be when the operation completes. View controllers are typically instantiated as a result of user input in the navigation.

Comment: It's just in a class that is separate from the main ViewController, and will be in a different file (in the future) than the main ViewController.swift. I just thought there's gotta be a global var that is an instance of main VC that I could simply reference. But I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can achieve this,

**1. Use Protocols or Delegates**

You said "**I have a class that is a** **GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate**." Write a protocol implementation in that class and make your view controller subscribe to that delegate, when you get delegate call back for your GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate do neccessary check and fire your custom delegate to the view controller, pass the data as an argument to the delegate method. In the view controller get the data and update the IBOutlet.

**2. Use NSNotificationCenter (dirty way of doing things, gotta be careful though)**

In your view controller class add an observer for the notification you are going to post like,

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateUI:", name: "didRecieveDataFromUDP", object: nil)
```

Add a method in your VC

```
 func updateUI(notifObject:NSNotification){
  let responseString = notifObject.object
  self.yourOutlet.string = responseString
}
```

and also remove the notification observer when you are done with the VC.
In the GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate delegate class when you get the call back with results fire this notification,

```
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("didRecieveDataFromUDP"", object: theResposenObjectYouNeedToSend)
```

**3. Use sharedInstances or mis-use the AppDelegate (not recommended)**

Create shared instances or singleton classes that will live through the app lifecycle and use them to store/retrieve data from any class or any thread.

Hope this helps, I wish you choose the first or second way.

Comment: Do you think first method would be the fastest of all?

Comment: of course it is fast, it is just like normal iOS foundation classes.